# Apply succesive shaders

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, glfw

Recently I've found the following [link](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/books/HTML/gpugems/gpugems_ch38.html) about simulating fluids on the GPU. I decided to try to implement it using OpenGL but I got stuck on how to apply successive shaders.

For example, I'd need to apply the advection shader, take its output and apply it into the difuse shader (from the link: "The operator is defined as the composition of operators for advection, diffusion, force application, and projection") but I can't figure out how. I've re-read learn opengl [framebuffers](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Framebuffers) tutorial but I'm still lost.

Right now I'm trying to do the following, to test communication between shaders:

1- load texture;

2- apply kernel 1 (inverse shader);

3- apply kernel 2 (advect shader);

Step 1 is done only once, while steps 2 and 3 are done while the windows is open.
Here is the shader code:

```c
/////////////////////////////
// read image - shader.frag
/////////////////////////////
#version 330 core

out vec4 FragColor;

in vec2 uv;

uniform sampler2D texture1;

void main()
{    
    FragColor = texture(texture1, uv);
}

/////////////////////////////
// color inversion shader
/////////////////////////////
#version 330 core

out vec4 FragColor;
in vec2 uv;

const float offset = 1.0 / 300.0;
void main()
{
    FragColor = vec4(vec3(1.0 - texture(screenTexture, uv)), 1.0);
}

/////////////////////////////
// advect shader
/////////////////////////////
#version 330 core

out vec4 FragColor;

in vec2 uv;

uniform float dt;
uniform float sigma_x_inv;
uniform sampler2D u;
uniform sampler2D x;

void main()
{
    // change texture2D to texture
    vec2 pos = uv - dt * sigma_x_inv * texture(u, uv).xy;
    FragColor = texture(x, pos);
}

/////////////////////////////
// vertex shader
/////////////////////////////
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;

out vec2 uv;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    uv = aPos.xy;
}
```

Here is part of my code, mostly taken from [here (learn opengl)](https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=src/4.advanced_opengl/5.1.framebuffers/framebuffers.cpp). The screen is just black. If I use one framebuffer(like shown in learn opengl) I can pass data to one shader just fine - I managed to see the inversion and advection shaders working in isolation - but when I add a new frame buffer the screen just goes black. I've also tried using one framebuffer for the two shaders but it didn't work.

Also, how could I pass two textures to one shader? The advection shader, for example, needs to textures, representing two different vector fields. Bellow is my code.

```cpp
#include "include/glad/glad.h"
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include "include/shader.hpp"

#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "include/stb_image.h"

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>


void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window);

unsigned int loadTexture(char const * path);

// settings
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;

unsigned int s_width = SCR_WIDTH;
unsigned int s_height = SCR_HEIGHT;

float sigma_x_inv = 1.0f / SCR_WIDTH;
const float dt = 1/60;

int main()
{
    // glfw: initialize and configure
    // ------------------------------
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

#ifdef __APPLE__
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
#endif

    // glfw window creation
    // --------------------
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);

    // glad: load all OpenGL function pointers
    // ---------------------------------------
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // build and compile our shader program
    // ------------------------------------
    Shader shader("shaders/shader.vert", "shaders/shader.frag");
    Shader advectShader("shaders/shader.vert", "shaders/advect.frag");
    Shader inversionShader("shaders/shader.vert", "shaders/inversion.frag");
    Shader boundaryShader("shaders/shader.vert", "shaders/boundary.frag");
    Shader divergenceShader("shaders/shader.vert", "shaders/divergence.frag");
    Shader gradientShader("shaders/shader.vert", "shaders/gradient.frag");

    // set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and configure vertex attributes
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    float planeVertices[] = { // vertex attributes for a quad that fills the entire screen in Normalized Device Coordinates.
        // positions   // texCoords
        -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
         1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,

        -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
         1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f
    };
    float quadVertices[] =
    {
        // vertex attributes for a quad that fills the entire screen in Normalized Device Coordinates.
        // positions   // texCoords
        -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
         1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,

        -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
         1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f
    };

    // plane VAO
    unsigned int planeVAO, planeVBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &planeVAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &planeVBO);
    glBindVertexArray(planeVAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, planeVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(planeVertices), &planeVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(float), (void*)(2 * sizeof(float)));

    // screen quad VAO
    unsigned int quadVAO, quadVBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &quadVAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &quadVBO);
    glBindVertexArray(quadVAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quadVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(quadVertices), &quadVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(float), (void*)(2 * sizeof(float)));


    // load and create a texture
    // -------------------------
    unsigned int texture1, texture2;
    // texture 1
    // ---------

    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true); // tell stb_image.h to flip loaded texture's on the y-axis.
    unsigned int blackTexture = loadTexture("textures/black.png");
    unsigned int awesomeTexture = loadTexture("textures/awesomeface.png");

    shader.use();
    shader.setInt("texture1", 0);

    // framebuffer configuration
    // -------------------------
    unsigned int framebuffer;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);

    // create a color attachment texture
    unsigned int textureColorbuffer;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureColorbuffer);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureColorbuffer);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, 0,
        GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
        GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureColorbuffer, 0);

    // framebuffer configuration
    // -------------------------
    unsigned int framebuffer2;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer2);
    
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer2);

    // create a color attachment texture
    unsigned int textureColorbuffer2;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureColorbuffer2);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureColorbuffer2);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, 0,
        GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
        GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureColorbuffer2, 0);

    // create a renderbuffer object for depth and
    // stencil attachment (we won't be sampling these)
    unsigned int rbo;
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rbo);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);

    // use a single renderbuffer object for both a depth AND stencil buffer.
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT);
    // now actually attach it
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);
    // now that we actually created the framebuffer and added all
    // attachments we want to check if it is actually complete now
    if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        std::cout << "ERROR::FRAMEBUFFER:: Framebuffer is not complete!" << std::endl;
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    // tell opengl for each sampler to which texture
    // unit it belongs to (only has to be done once)
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // advectShader.use(); // don't forget to activate/use the shader before setting uniforms!
    // // either set it manually like so:
    // advectShader.setInt("u", 0);
    // // or set it via the texture class
    // advectShader.setInt("x", 1);
    divergenceShader.use();
    divergenceShader.setFloat("sigma_x_inv", sigma_x_inv);

    boundaryShader.use();
    boundaryShader.setFloat("scale", 1.0f);

    shader.use();

    // Program start time
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    // render
    // ------
    // bind to framebuffer and draw scene as we normally would to color texture
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // enable depth testing (is disabled for rendering screen-space quad)

    glClearColor(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);

    shader.use();
    glBindVertexArray(planeVAO);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, awesomeTexture);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    // render loop
    // -----------
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // input
        // -----
        processInput(window);

        // ----

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer2);
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        inversionShader.use();
        glBindVertexArray(planeVAO);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureColorbuffer2);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);



        // test boy
        // -----------------------------
        // now bind back to default framebuffer and draw a quad plane
        // with the attached framebuffer color texture
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        // glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        // glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


        // density step
        // -----------------------------
        // boundaryShader.use();
        // boundaryShader.setFloat("scale", 1.0f);
        // boundaryShader.setVec2("offset", 0.5, 0.5);

        // pass current time to shader
        advectShader.use();
        auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<float> diff = now - start;
        advectShader.setFloat("dt", diff.count());
        advectShader.setFloat("sigma_x_inv", 1000 * 1 / s_width);

        glBindVertexArray(quadVAO);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureColorbuffer);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

        // needs to check how to get shader

        // velocity step
        // -----------------------------




        // glfw: swap buffers and poll IO events (keys pressed/released, mouse moved etc.)
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    // optional: de-allocate all resources once they've outlived their purpose:
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &planeVAO);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &quadVAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &planeVBO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &quadVBO);
    glDeleteFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);

    // glfw: terminate, clearing all previously allocated GLFW resources.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

// process all input: query GLFW whether relevant keys are pressed/released this frame and react accordingly
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
}

// glfw: whenever the window size changed (by OS or user resize) this callback function executes
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    s_width = width;
    s_height = height;
    // make sure the viewport matches the new window dimensions; note that width and
    // height will be significantly larger than specified on retina displays.
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

// utility function for loading a 2D texture from file
// ---------------------------------------------------
unsigned int loadTexture(char const * path)
{
    unsigned int textureID;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureID);

    int width, height, nrComponents;
    unsigned char *data = stbi_load(path, &width, &height, &nrComponents, 0);
    if (data)
    {
        GLenum format;
        if (nrComponents == 1)
            format = GL_RED;
        else if (nrComponents == 3)
            format = GL_RGB;
        else if (nrComponents == 4)
            format = GL_RGBA;

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, width, height, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        // set the texture wrapping parameters
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        // set texture filtering parameters
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        stbi_image_free(data);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Texture failed to load at path: " << path << std::endl;
        stbi_image_free(data);
    }

    return textureID;
}
```

Comment: I think `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureColorbuffer2);` may fail because at that point texture is bound to the current framebuffer `framebuffer2`. You really need to perform error handling everywhere otherwise it will be an endless struggle to locate the problematic spot.

Comment: Hm, how would I go about error handling? Just adding `std::cout << glGetError() << std::endl;` after every line?

Comment: A real-life project would require some C++ wrappers that will deal with errors and inconsistent state. But for now `glGetError()` after every operation should be sufficient.

Comment: No errors where raised. I called it after every line after the first framebuffer creation.

Comment: Hmm, `textureColorbuffer2` is a backing texture for `framebuffer2` so it can't be right to select it as input texture when `framebuffer2` is current.

Comment: I've just checked again and no errors were thrown. I've edited the question to have the entire code.